# Is it possible to use hooks in _document.js (NextJS)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to append a class to my body tag depending on the locale. So if someone visits from Spain, I will append a class which changes the Tailwind theming to match the branding of that country.

My body tag is located in a custom _document.js file. When I try to `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'`, I get the 'breaking rules of hooks' error in React. I need this hook to detect the locale and therefore append the class if necessary.

Is it possible to use hooks in _document.js? If not, why not?

Comment: _document is only rendered in the server, move your logic to _app instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The body tag is in _document, is it possible to pass props to _document? If not, should the <body> tag go in _app? Sorry if these are silly questions!

Comment: If you want to add something to body you can do like in _app.tsx. For example:- ` useEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute("dir", getDirection(locale));
  }, [locale]);`